# Instance of class java

Tags: java, class, instance

I have that snippet of code:

```
    abstract class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    (...)
       public boolean equals(Objct o){
          if(o instanceof Fruit){
             Fruit that = (Fruit)o;
          } else return false;
       }
    }
```

What it means, what does it do?: `Fruit that = (Fruit)o;`

I create in this way an instance (that) of class Fruit, but what `(Fruit)o` means?

Comment: o instanceof Fruit makes sure that the Object o is of type Fruit so that you can safely call methods from the Fruit class on the object (it ensures you're not trying to call methods from the Fruit class on a non Fruit object) and Fruit = (Fruit) o  casts the Object o to a Fruit object so you have access to methods in the Fruit class

Comment: @peggy Thank you very much, now I understand..

Comment: no problem glad i could help. welcome to stack overflow